# Django CSP unable to make it work with Bootstrap Icons

Tags: django, content-security-policy, bootstrap-icons, django-csp

setings.py:

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = ('script-src', )
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'",
     "rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65",
     "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",)
     

CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'", "'unsafe-inline'",
                  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js")
```

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" 
          integrity="sha512-YFENbnqHbCRmJt5d+9lHimyEMt8LKSNTMLSaHjvsclnZGICeY/0KYEeiHwD1Ux4Tcao0h60tdcMv+0GljvWyHg=="
          crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Browser Console:
Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-icons/1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css (“style-src”).

I have already tried to add them to  CSP_STYLE_SRC, CSP_IMG_SRC and to CSP_DEFAULT_SRC.
What am i missing?